# Correct way to use hybridModel function in grouped time series forecast?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical

I'm wondering what is the correct way to pass in the hybridModel function from the forecastHybrid package to a grouped time series forecast?

I am able to use forecast.gts on my training data (y.TR) which is just a gts object for all months except the last 3. 
Working code:

```
    library(forecastHybrid)
    library(hts)
    FC <- forecast.gts(y.TR, h=3, method="comb", weights="nseries",                 
    fmethod="arima", algorithms="cg",parallel=TRUE, num.cores=4)
```

Now instead of using the Arima method to forecast the time series at each level I want to use hybridmodel as a custom function so that I'll have an ensemble forecast for each series at each level

not working:

```
    training_forecast <- forecast.gts(y.TR, h=3, method="comb",         
    weights="nseries",parallel=TRUE, num.cores=4, models = "ae", FUN =          
    hybridModel)
```

I also tried:

```
    training_forecast <- forecast(y.TR,h=3, models = "ae",  FUN =        
    hybridModel)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error in forecast.hybridModel(models, h = h) : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I was basing what I was trying on a question a guy asked here:
    https://github.com/ellisp/forecastHybrid/issues/74

From what I saw in this post it seems like this should be possible 
(I know I can fit a separate hybridmodel for each series in a loop and use combineF on them but when I tested it is very slow compared to using forecast.gts)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think You should enter the HybridModel as a function like this.

I used the htseg2 dataset which is include in the package.

```
 training_forecast <- forecast.gts(y.TR, h=3, 
   method="comb", weights="nseries",
   parallel=TRUE, num.cores=4, FUN = function(x){hybridModel(x, models="ae")}
```

If you didn't chose `VERBOSE = FALSE` you should have this kind of outcome.

```
Fitting the auto.arima model
Fitting the ets model
Fitting the auto.arima model
Fitting the ets model
Fitting the auto.arima model
Fitting the ets model
Fitting the auto.arima model
```

However, I think it's impossible to get the specification of each models.

Comment: Since you are suggesting an answer to an old unanswered question, it would be very helpful to support your answer by showing the resulting outcome your code produced.